# How to change kendo grid selected page number without rebinding?

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with custom binding, the selected page is informed by the datasource (sent by the server). Everything is working, only part missing is how to set the selected page to the information in the JSON response.

The JSON sent by the server is something like this:

> {AggregateResults: null, Data: […], Errors: null, Page: 2, Total: 300}

I did a custom DataSourceResult class, and tried to set the pager and datasource page in the RequestEnd datasource event to the one above, but in both cases, a new call is made to the server.

Comment: DataSourceResult handles everything for you, no manual work needed. If you want everything client-side set `ServerOperation(false)` which fetches all data on a single request allowing you to page, sort, group without rebinding.

Comment: You missed the point @BishnuRawal, I want everything, including setting the page number, server side, and through AJAX, setting the selected page number is the only part I can't do, once I try, the DataSource do a new request to the server.

Comment: Where you exactly want to set the page number? Can you provide some code details? I am still confused.

Comment: @BishnuRawal the "1" inside a blue circle in the KendoUI Grid (see link [link]http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html )